# What does GridView1.EditIndex = -1 mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I found the following statement in the `OnRowCancelingEdit` event in an ASP.NET project, but I'm not sure what it means:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
```

Comment: yes edit event is the event called from onrowcancelingedit of .aspx page.

Comment: `EditIndex is Gets or sets the index of the row to edit.` So when you dont have any row to edit you will write -1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a great resource... MSDN is always worth a check.

From [`GridView.EditIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The zero-based index of the row to edit.
>
> **The default is -1, which indicates that no row is being edited.**  *(my emphasis)*

Comment: Actually it was my first question in Stack Exchange. Will sure implement you suggestion in future. thanks for the help.